# How to read Empty Data from the Xml tags using DOm Parser

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, domparser

I have a emergency requirment to read Xml data  from xml file and store it in Text file.My issue is i can able to read Data from xml tag and store it in text file but i am mssing the tag values which are empty , even i want to read both data and empty values of tag and store it in Text File.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790153/reading-xml-data-in-to-text-file



<company>
        <staff>
            <firstname>John</firstname>
            <lastname>Kaith</lastname>
            <nickname></nickname>
            <Department>Sales Manager</Department>
        </staff>
        <staff>
            <firstname>Sharon</firstname>
            <lastname>Eunis</lastname>
            <nickname></nickname>
            <Department></Department>
        </staff>
        <staff>
            <firstname>Shiny</firstname>
            <lastname></lastname>
            <nickname></nickname>
            <Department>SAP Consulting</Department>
        </staff>
    </company>
```

code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) 
             {      
                 Node node = nList.item(i);  

                 if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)    
                 {         
                      Element eElement = (Element) node; 

                     if(eElement.hasChildNodes())    
                     {               
                         NodeList nl = node.getChildNodes();  

                         for(int j=0; j<nl.getLength(); j++)  
                         {                   
                             Node nd = nl.item(j);   
                             String name= nd.getTextContent().trim();
                             if (name !=null && !name.trim().equals(""))
                             {
                             String v=name.trim();
                             System.out.print(v +",");   
                             writer.write(nd.getTextContent() + ",");
                             }

                     } 
                         System.out.println(data);
                        System.out.print("\n");

                         writer.write("\n");
                         }        
                         } }
```

Output for this code:

```
John,kaith,Sales Manager,
sharon,Eunis,
shiny,SAP consulting,
```

Expected Output:

```
John,kaith, ,Sales Manager,
 sharon,Eunis, , ,
shiny, , ,SAP consulting,
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this:

```
if (name !=null && !name.trim().equals(""))
```

your problem ? You're actively rejecting blank text elements.

Comment: yes that is my problem, if i removing that  line i am getting unlimited commas in between

Comment: I want solution for that code, i know                             if (name !=null && !name.trim().equals(""))  is the issue, if u know please suggest me with right answer